# How to create an Observable from CLLocationManager updates

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, rx-swift

I am using `RxSwift` library in my app. I am trying to convert my app logic for processing GPS location updates and move that over to an observable. For that, I have been using this code as baseline:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/GeolocationExample/GeolocationViewController.swift

However, in the code above, the updates are delivered directly to an UIElement via the UIView extension. This is of no use to me, as I need these updates to be delivered to a non-UI observer variable for further background processing.

I am new to RxSwift and I am not aware how to build the type of Observer that I need in this case. Neither have I been able to find this within RxSwift documentation.

I would appreciate if someone can comment on how to achieve this implementation of CLLocationManager with RxSwift.

Answer (score 1):

Found out there is no need to create an Observer, there is the following possibility within the observable itself:

`let geolocationObservable = geolocationService.location
    .drive(onNext: { (location: CLLocation) in
        print(location.altitude)
        }, onCompleted: { 
            //TODO
        }) { 
            //TODO
}`